# Generic function getting a generic parameter

Tags: c#, generics

This is probably some stupid oversight, but here it goes:

```
public class Entity<TId> where TId : IEquatable<TId>
{
    public virtual TId Id { get; private set; }
}

public class Client : Entity<Guid> { }
public class State : Entity<short> { }


public class Helper
{
    protected IList<Client> clients;
    protected IList<State> states;

    //Works
    public T Get<T>()
    {
        return default(T);
    }

    public T Get<T>(Guid id) where T : Entity<Guid>
    {
        return default(T);
    }

    public T Get<T>(short id) where T : Entity<short>
    {
        return default(T);

    }
}
```

How the heck do I write the Get function that will work with both of the classes? And with every other that inherits from Entity?

I just hope I don't get too many downvotes.
:(

**Edit**

This is where it'll be used. So it won't be just two classes. But basically all the classes on my model.

```
    //What should I declare here?
    {
        TEntity result = default(TEntity);
        try
        {
            using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                result = session.Query<TEntity>().Where(e => e.Id == Id).FirstOrDefault();
            }
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

**With the solution given by SWeko**

```
public TEntity Get<TEntity, TId>(TId Id)
            where TEntity : Entity<TId>
            where TId : IEquatable<TId>
        {
            try
            {
                TEntity result = default(TEntity);
                using (var tx = statefullSession.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    result = statefullSession.Query<TEntity>().Where(e => e.Id.Equals(Id)).FirstOrDefault();
                }
                return result; 
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the issue is just what to put in the `where` clause of the `Get` method, you could do:

```
public TEntity Get<TEntity, TId> (TId id) where TEntity : Entity<TId>
                                          where TId : IEquatable<TId>
{
  .....
}
```

Comment: Error 1 - The type 'TId' cannot be used as type parameter 'TId' in the generic type or method 'ConsoleApplication1.Entity<TId>'. There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'TId' to 'System.IEquatable<TId>' :(

Comment: An additional `where TId : IEquatable<TId>` is needed for this to compile.

Comment: @mikez: added, sorry for the half-baked answer

Comment: +1. Yes it's probably what the OP wants. Two generic parameters are required.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the need for generic `Get` methods, since you want to return objects of types known in advance (Clients, States) from two lists that are predefined.

```
public class Helper
{
    protected IList<Client> clients;
    protected IList<State> states;

    public Client GetClient(Guid id)
    {
        return clients.Where(c => c.Id == id);
    }

    public State GetState(short id)
    {
        return states.Where(s => s.Id == id);
    }
}
```

Consider using dictionaries for speed, where the id is used as key.

---

Alternatively you could base the two public Get methods on one private generic Get method

```
private TEntity Get<TEntity,TId>(IList<TEntity> list, TId id)
{
    return list.Where(item => item.Id == id);
}

public Client GetClient(Guid id)
{
    return Get(clients, id);
}

public State GetState(short id)
{
    return Get(states, id);
}
```